# Excel Increment when IF=true

Tags: excel, excel-2013

i have 10 datas. every data only 4 of them say the correct answer. i want to add the exact value 4 at my cell with increment if the value is true.
My pseudocode below:

`i=0
IF(Range F4:F10 = 4)==i++
Show i;`

i try this in excel logical bar but it didnt work as what i want. i do search many many example but i still dont get it what should it works?

```
=IF(N3:N12=4,"F4+1","F4+0")
```

i dont know the real correct 1 for condition and value F4++.
can anyone help me ?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(N3:N12,4)`

Comment: @ScottCraner SOLVED, thankks

Comment: @ScottCraner, this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @sifu Depends on ones opinion.  1) I have put answers to ones such as this and been voted down.  2) my rule of thumb is if there are better questions for the same answer out there(which there are), and it takes longer to find them than to just answer I put it in the comments.  3) this one will eventually be closed due to it being a duplicate and/or off topic so it will not come up in searches and the only one being helped is the OP.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the explanation, I understand what you mean.